# Can same TC be executed by two different users in TestLink?

Tags: testlink

Can same Test Case be executed by two different users in TestLink?

Same test case (under the same test plan) can be assigned for execution to two different users, but can they be actually executed?

I can't see any "Save Execution Result" button for the second user once the test case is executed by first user. So as per my knowledge it can't be executed. But still wanted to confirm whether is it possible? or Does TestLink provides such a functionality/feature?

Comment: Yes It can be saved. you can refer history as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The most recent is displayed as the current result. But you will see both in the execution history.

The second user should execute the test in the exact same way as the first user. I.e select the result state and click save or save and next.

If they can't I would check the second user has access to execute tests on that plan / project. Are they able to run tests that are in the not attempted state?

Also what version of testlink are you running? My experience is mainly with v1.9.3

Comment: Given that the OP isn't seeing the save button, perhaps you could update your answer to explain how the second user saves the test case results - it's possible the OP's second user may have browser compatibility problems that are preventing the save button from displaying.